# Not sure why my Azure CLI is not showing python as a language option while creating azure http trigger function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli

I am trying to create a python function, but when I run 'func new', I do not see python while making selection of language. Can anyone point out some good literature where I can see what's going wrong. Also, it will be very helpful for me, if someone can list good links for getting started with programming of python function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Comment: probably outdated? try updating it to the latest version

Comment: double check the version of `func` you have. Python was added recently and you may need to update your tools.

Answer (score 1):

By following that document, you will get the selection of template instead of the selection of language. You will get the selection of worker runtime when you create the function project.

[image]

You must meet the prerequisites.

[image]

Here is the [Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) for your reference. Note that Python for Azure Function is currently in preview. There might be some drawbacks.